# difficulty in using SAX parser for same named parent child nodes

Tags: java, xml-parsing, saxparser

Here is the xml to be parsed.
   I want to use sax parser to parse this xml but it is

```
<Plans>
 <Plan ID="1" Name="Plan-A">
  <Plan ID="4" Name="Plan-A1">
<Content ID="1"    Description="Testing plans 123"/>
 <Content ID="2" Description="Testing plans 2222"/>
 </Plan>
 <Plan ID="5" Name="Plan-A2">
  <Content ID="3" Description="Testing plans 55551111"/>
</Plan>
</Plan>
</Plans>
```

these plan tabs can go upto N-levels 
Can any one there help me find out how to parse it in SAX parser
here is the PlansDTO i created for it.

```
public class PlansDTO {
    String _id;
String _name;
String _child_id;
boolean _hasChild;
Vector _childIds;
Hashtable _plans;
Vector contentDTOs;

}
```

I am having difficulty in handling this tree through sax parser , can any one there help me ?

Comment: What have you tried and what are your difficulties? It's hard to help without any details.

Answer (score 2):

SAX is a context-free parser, so, if you need context, you have to do it by yourself : your parser should therefore have a reference to the last "plan" instance that has started.

You may also consider using another parser like DOM or JAXB : these parsers will keep the context for you.